# Cleaning up bindings and change listeners on nested properties when parent properties change in javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a model class with `SimpleXXXXProperty` properties. Javafx GUI elements are updated using either bindings or change listeners, e.g.

```
textField.textProperty().bind(myModel.myModelStatus());
```

or

```
myModel.myModelStatus().addListener((obj,oldv.newv) -> { update here });
```

When the instance of the model class changes, I rebind the controls and add the listeners again. However, I can see by the memory use that the old model still persists in memory.

What do I have to do to remove all references to the model so it can be cleaned up?

- Unbind before binding again
- Remove the listeners
- Both

Is there are more automatic way of updating bindings and listeners on nested properties when the parent property changes?

Comment: How do you remove listeners that are implemented as lambda expressions?

Comment: If you have only bindings, then there shouldn't be any memory leaks if you do not hold any reference of the model object anywhere else. If you used any listener, then you need to remove them (which means you cannot use inline lambda, because there is no way to remove those).

Comment: If a property `p1` is bound to another property `p2` and there's a reference to `p1` there's also a reference to `p2`. If you use a listener and a listener to `p1` and it references a object `o`, as long as there is a reference to `p1` there's a reference to `o`. Unbinding/binding to a different property and removing the listener should change this and make the objects available for garbage collection as long as there is no reference to them via some other objects. Removing a lambda expression without storing it somewhere should be impossible though. (GC may not claim objects immediately btw.)

Comment: @fabian I have a lot of nested bindings and listeners... Sounds like it might be easier to make the model class `final` and change its properties internally rather than create a new instance.

Comment: You can also use a `WeakInvalidationListener` or a `WeakChangeListener`, but both are not thought to be used for your explicit rebind-scenario.

Comment: I think it is also important to note that GC can always choose to delay memory reclamation as mentioned by @fabian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Points to consider when you want to undo bindings (including listeners) to your model:

- Undirectional bindings (`p1.bind(p2)`) are automatically unbound when binding the same property again (e.g. `p1.bind(p3)`), but it does not hurt to do it explicitely (`p1.unbind()`).
- Bidirectional bindings (`p1.bindBidirectional(p2)` or `Bindings.bindBidirectional(p1, p2)`) have to be unbound explicitely (`p1.unbindBidirectional(p2)` or `Bindings.unbindBidirectional(p1, p2)`).
- Listeners must be unregistered (`prop.removeListener(l)`).

The third is the tricky part, as listeners are often implemented as lambda expressions or method references. Unfortunately, lambda expressions as well as method references(!) are *not* constant:

```
// lambdas are not constant
InvalidationListener l1 = obs -> {};
InvalidationListener l2 = obs -> {};

assert l1 != l2; // they are NOT identical!
```

Well, this might be obvious for lambdas, but the same is also true for method references, which is really annoying:

```
// method references are not constant
Runnable runnable1 = this::anyMethod;
Runnable runnable2 = this::anyMethod;

assert runnable1 != runnable2; // they are NOT identical!
```

That means, you cannot register a lambda expression or a simple method reference as listener if you want to be able to unregister it:

```
// if you register listeners on a property like that...
label.textProperty().addListener(obs -> System.out.println(obs));
label.textProperty().addListener(this::handleLabelInvalid);

// ...these calls WON'T remove them due to the inequality shown above!
label.textProperty().removeListener(obs -> System.out.println(obs));
label.textProperty().removeListener(this::handleLabelInvalid);
```

**Solution**

You have to store a reference to the lambda expression or method referency by yourself. I use to use final fields for that:

```
public class MyClass {
    // store references for adding/removal
    private final InvalidationListener l1 = this::handleLabelInvalid;
    private final InvalidationListener l2 = obs -> System.out.println(obs);

    ...

    public void bind() {
        label.textProperty().addListener(l1);
        label.textProperty().addListener(l2);
    }

    public void unbind() {
        label.textProperty().removeListener(l1);
        label.textProperty().removeListener(l2);
    }

    private void handleLabelInvalid(Observable observable) { ... }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to manually call `unbind()` though, if there is a new binding done on the same property.

Comment: @Jai if it is `bindBidirectional` would it be needed?

Comment: @geometrikal Good point. Yes you do need to. And you need to remove via `prop.unbindBidirectional(oldProp)` (i.e. you need to know what was the old property).

Comment: @Jai you're right. I've modified the first part of my answer to address both issues - unidirectional and bidirectional bindings.